# How do you combine dictionaries' key values if they have another key value that is the same while leaving out the dictionary that was not combined?

Tags: python, list, for-loop, object

I have a list of objects, like so:

```
[ 
  {"title":"cdap_tests", "datacenter":"B1", "count_failed": 1},
  {"title":"cdap_tests", "datacenter":"G1", "count_failed": 1},
  {"title":"cdap_tests", "datacenter":"GOV1", "count_failed": 1},
  {"title":"developer_portal_tests", "datacenter":"B1", "count_failed": 1}
]
```

and I want to combine the objects that have the same title attribute together like so:

```
[ 
  {"title":"cdap_tests", "datacenter":"B1,G1,GOV1", "count_failed": 1},
  {"title":"developer_portal_tests", "datacenter":"B1", "count_failed": 1}
]
```

I have tried comparing each one to another based on their attribute, and adding the string to the other string if they were the same, but for some reason it is not combining them, I simply get the same data back from the function return

```
    new_data_list = []
    for row_to_compare_to in data:
        for row_to_compare_from in data:
            if row_to_compare_from["datacenter"] == row_to_compare_to["datacenter"]:
                pass
            elif row_to_compare_from["title"] == row_to_compare_to["title"]:
                row_to_compare_to["datacenter"] = f"{row_to_compare_from['datacenter']}, {row_to_compare_to['datacenter']}"
                row_to_compare_to["count_failed"] = f"{row_to_compare_from['count_failed']}, {row_to_compare_to['count_failed']}"
        new_data_list.append(row_to_compare_to)
    return new_data_list
```

Could someone point me in the direction of what I am doing wrong? Or maybe a cleaner solution?

Comment: In Python terminology, the objects inside your list are dictionaries.  The strings to the left of each colon are called keys (e.g `"title"`, `"datacenter"`) and to the right are called values (e.g. `"cdap_tests"`, `"B1"`).  Before answering, two questions:

1. Are you always matching on the value associated with `"title"`?
2. Do you need to count every time, say, `"B1"` appears for `"datacenter"` or just count if it has appeared at all?

Comment: Thanks for your help @Frodnar, and thanks for the terminology. 1. Yes, it is always being matched on the title 2. if it appears with the same name and same datacenter, than I have a bug somewhere else in my code. So to answer your question, B1 will only appear AT MOST once per title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code produces an error because the `"count_failed"` is not in every dictionary.

If I were starting from scratch, I might substitute the original `data` list for a dictionary of dictionaries where the key to the outer dictionary is the title of each entry.  This would result in code that is easier to read.  I might also make the appended data like `"B1,G1,GOV1"` a list instead `["B1", "G1", "GOV1"]`.

I'm sure my approach isn't the most efficient or Pythonic, but I believe it works:

```
new_data_list = []
for raw_dct in data:
    if raw_dct['title'] in [dct['title'] for dct in new_data_list]:
        for new_dct in new_data_list:
            if raw_dct['title'] == new_dct['title']:
                for k, v in raw_dct.items():
                    if k in new_dct.keys():
                        if type(v) is str:
                            if v not in new_dct[k]:
                                new_dct[k] += "," + str(v)
                        if type(v) is int:
                            new_dct[k] += v
                    else:
                        new_dct[k] = v
    else:
        new_data_list.append(raw_dct)
```

which gives your desired `new_data_list` that also takes into account the counting of integer attributes like `"count_failed"`.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Frodnar! Im not sure this would work though because it compares all k, v in the raw_dct.items(). I only want to compare them if the. title is the same, if they are not the same they should be skipped. This however I believe would compare the datacenters  to eachother as well. I made an update to my code to include the count_failed variable to make it more clear. Any suggestions with this information?

Comment: It would be nice if I could add the count_failed as a comma separated list as well if they are combined by title, but I can probably figure that out.

Comment: `if raw_dct['title'] == new_dct['title']:` compares the titles.  If the titles are not the same, then it does not compare the dictionaries any further.  Could you provide input that contains more examples or output that shows my answer above deviates from the expected behavior?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that you changed your input and expected output.  I will adjust the code.